# onItemSelectedListener only triggered if selection actually change?

Tags: android, spinner

I use `setOnItemSelectedListener` on a spinner.
The listener is triggered if I change the selection but not if I select the same item that is already selected.
I need to be nofified even if the user select the same item that is already selected.
I tought about using `setOnItemClickListener` but it is not supported by the `Spinner`.

Any hints ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still looking for a solution to this question, Regis, it may be worth having a look at [a related question I asked a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975394/how-to-use-android-spinner-like-a-drop-down-list/7980739#7980739), which has several answers with good ideas on how to work around this issue.

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais: I was wondering why I'd got an accept and a downvote within a few seconds of each other... funnily enough, it earned me a gold badge for having 10 zero-score accepted answers :-)

Comment: If you edit your answer I will then be able to undo my downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried to override `onNothingSelected()`? in `onNS()` you implement to do/get/whatever item that is selected by "default". I hope you get my idea.

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // Some operation with other selection
                            }
    @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    //operation with that item that onItemSelected() did not triggered. I mean, let's say you have 3 items on the spinner: A,B,C. Initially what we see its the A item and on this item this method will apply.
    }});
```

Comment: I did try onItemSelected but not onNothingSelected. The doc is not realy clear on what it does. I will give it a try next monday and get back to you.

Comment: onNothingSelected does not do what I need. In fact I was not able to find how to trigger it.

Comment: Did you override it? It must be overrided inside the `new OnItemSelectedListener()`...

Comment: Yes. onItemSelected is triggered when a new selection is made but onNothingSelected is never triggered.

Comment: The doc says onNothingSelected: Callback method to be invoked when the selection disappears from this view.